# What are the advantages of sqli over sql?

Tags: sql, mysqli

I would like to know more from the security perspective. What are the advantages of sqli over sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about the PHP MySQL extensions mysql and mysqli.

Besides the fact that [the mysql extension is deprecated since PHP 5.5.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and should not be used in new projects anymore, [the mysqli docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php) actually list the most important improvements:

> The mysqli extension has a number of benefits, the key enhancements
>   over the mysql extension being:
>
> - Object-oriented interface
> - Support for Prepared Statements
> - Support for Multiple Statements
> - Support for Transactions
> - Enhanced debugging capabilities
> - Embedded server support

**From a security perspective**, *Support for Prepared Statements* would probably your strongest argument for the new extension. [Prepared Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.html) are your [best defense against SQL injections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-prepared-statements-can-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks).